# UIScrollView и всплывающая клавиатура - скролл к активному текстовому полю

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Братия, все сдаюсь :) Помогите!

Имеем 10 полей UITextView для ввода на 1-м экране. Как только мы клацаем по одному из них, выдвигается клавиатура и прячет половину экрана. 
Я добавил UIScrollView, который тут же "включается" и позволяет скролить экран:

```
IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

...

-(void)keyboardWillShowNotification:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 45, 320, 200);
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 360)];
}
```

Так же и выключаем, когда клавиатура "уходит".

А теперь вопрос: Правильно ли я сделал? И главное! Как сделать что бы scrollview "фокусировался" на выбранном поле ввода (если например нажали по нижнему)???

ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ №1:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
scrollView.contentOffset = (CGPoint) {0, CGRectGetMinY(textField.frame)};
scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 45, 320, 200);
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 400)];
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 45, 320, 500);
}
```

Comment: То есть вы включаете scrollView для того, чтобы юзер мог "вытащить" спрятанное под клавиатурой поле? Если так, то это не лучшее решение, лучше было бы поднять view (изменить frame) автоматически, вы же знаете высоту клавиатуры. А когда клавиатура прячется, вернуть старый frame. Для этого scrollView вообще не нужна.

Comment: Анастасия, а разве правильно? Ведь я так целиком view переназначаю. вроде как не кашерно :)

Comment: View остается та же, просто у нее меняется frame. Да, она перерисовывается с новым фреймом, когда выезжает клавиатура, но ведь и scrollView перерисовывается, когда вы ее скроллите (вручную или программно), так что вроде бы ничего некошерного нету.

Comment: У меня кончилась возможность комментирования под своим ответом и скоро кончится по ваши вопросом. Я в течение 10 минут обновлю свой ответ ссылкой на zip болваночного проекта.

Comment: Обновил свой ответ.

Comment: Кстати, Анастасия, подход со сдвигом фрейма, конечно, тоже должен работать. Мой подход со скроллом тоже работает нормально. Подождем, чтобы узнать, в чем на самом деле сложности у автора вопроса.

Comment: Я проверил оба подхода на тестовом проекте (который доступен на Гитхабе) и убедился в том, что у обоих подходов есть нюансы, которые нужно будет учитывать и подкручивать в реальной ситуации.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваше решение с `keyboardWillShowNotification:` вам не подойдет, так как согласно [документации](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIKeyboardWillShowNotification) объект `aNotification` не содержит информации о текстовом поле, которое спровоцировало появление клавиатуры, а эта информация вам нужна для того, чтобы знать куда делать скролл.

Вместе этого пользуйтесь просто стандартными методами протокола [UITextViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextViewDelegate):

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    yourScrollView.contentOffset = (CGPoint){
        0, // ось x нас не интересует
        CGRectGetMinY(textView.frame) // Скроллим скролл к верхней границе текстового поля - Вы можете настроить эту величину по своему усмотрению
    };
}

- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    yourScrollView.contentOffset = (CGPoint){0, 0}; // Возвращаем скролл в начало, так как редактирование текстового поля закончено
}
```

Надеюсь, вы знаете, как задать свойство `delegate` для всех ваших объектов UITextView. Если нет - пишите и я дополню свой ответ.

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ 1**

Итак, я сделал простой проект, который показывает, что я имел в виду. Наша задача - добавить в него специфику того, что вам нужно, и будет добро всем нам)

Вот инструкция, как скачать проект (я надеюсь, что вы имеете представление о работе с Git):

Склонируйте проект. Для этого введите в консоли:

```
git clone https://github.com/stanislaw/Hashcode
```

Потом загляните в папку

```
Hashcode / iOS / 20130715_236725 / (Пусть числа вас не пугают: первое число - это всего лишь сегодняшняя дата, а второе - это номер этого вашего топика здесь на ХэшКоде)
```

Внутри проект 236725.xcodeproj - запустите его, и гляньте, чего вам не хватает для успешного результата?!

Если вы в смятении, можете связаться со мной по скайпу, который указан в моем здешнем профиле - и я все расскажу голосом, так как устал уже сегодня писать длинные простыни разъяснительного текста. Я не кусаюсь, вы - надеюсь тоже ;)

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ 2**

Я сделал рабочий вариант-решение обсуждаемого здесь вопроса. Я снова поместил его на Гитхаб - советую не ограничиться лишь просмотром кода в броузере, а все-таки скачать его и посмотреть, о чем идет речь. Я надеюсь, что это не банальное отсутствие навыков работы с Github заставляет многих пасовать перед тем, чтобы взять и склонировать проекты, содержащие примеры, имеющие прямо отношение к вопросам, которое они же и задают. [[@dark_Haron](/users/13183/dark_haron)](/users/13183/dark_haron), я пишу не лично вам, а скорее в воздух, ХэшКоду, так как сталкиваюсь с желанием "бегло просмотреть" то, что я привожу в примеры, без взаимодействия с Git (это же просто git clone и пример уже у вас), многократно.

Вот ключевой код ViewController из моего примера:

```
// .h
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) UITextField *currentTextField;

@property BOOL keyboardIsPresent;

@end

// .m
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Подписываемся на события клавиатуры
    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(keyboardWillShowNotification:)
               name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
             object:nil];

    [nc addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(keyboardWillHideNotification:)
               name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
             object:nil];

    self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:screenFrame()];
    self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor grayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];

    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];

    UITextField *textField;

    textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), 30)];
    textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    textField.placeholder = @"Enter the text 1";
    textField.delegate = self;

    [self.scrollView addSubview:textField];

    textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 400, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), 30)];
    textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    textField.placeholder = @"Enter the text 2";
    textField.delegate = self;

    [self.scrollView addSubview:textField];

    textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 800, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), 30)];
    textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    textField.placeholder = @"Enter the text 3";
    textField.delegate = self;

    [self.scrollView addSubview:textField];

    // Чисто фиктивный лабел, который изображает область до которой вы хотите иметь возможность доскролливать в Вашем реальном приложении
    UILabel *bottomLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 900, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), 100)];
    bottomLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    bottomLabel.text = @"ПОДВАЛ";

    [self.scrollView addSubview:bottomLabel];

    // Выставляем размер области скролла по низу подвала
    self.scrollView.contentSize = (CGSize){0, CGRectGetMaxY(bottomLabel.frame)}; 
}

- (void)scrollToTextField:(UITextField *)textField {
    // fminf нужен для того, чтобы в случае самых нижних текстовых полей скролл не заваливался за границу скролла (желающие могут попробовать убрать эту поправку и посмотреть, насколько плачевным будет результат)
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:(CGPoint){
        0,
        fminf(CGRectGetMinY(textField.frame), self.scrollView.contentSize.height - CGRectGetHeight(self.scrollView.frame))
    } animated:YES];
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    self.currentTextField = textField;

    if (self.keyboardIsPresent) {
        [self scrollToTextField:self.currentTextField];
    }
}

- (void)keyboardWillShowNotification:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    CGRect keyboardScreenRect = [[[aNotification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];

    CGSize contentSize = self.scrollView.contentSize;
    contentSize.height += CGRectGetHeight(keyboardScreenRect);
    self.scrollView.contentSize = contentSize;

    [self scrollToTextField:self.currentTextField];

    self.keyboardIsPresent = YES;
}

-(void)keyboardWillHideNotification:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    CGRect keyboardScreenRect = [[[aNotification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];

    CGSize contentSize = self.scrollView.contentSize;
    contentSize.height -= CGRectGetHeight(keyboardScreenRect);
    self.scrollView.contentSize = contentSize;

    self.keyboardIsPresent = NO;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    self.currentTextField = nil;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}
```

Постороннему наблюдателю может показаться, что код слишком усложнен. Что ж, если сможете показать на моем примере-коде, как можно добиться того же результата более простым кодом, буду признателен. Скажу лишь, что главная проблема, которую я решал, это то, чтобы при скролле к будущему текущему текстовому полю и при появлении клавиатуры при изменении размеров скролла у ...скролла, ...чтобы на его границе не возникало специфической "дыры", которая портит все впечатление от анимации - хотите - можете поэкспериментировать.

Comment: Вам следует изменить формулировку заголовка вашего вопроса - на Хэшкоде не принято писать вопросы в слишком общей форме. Предлагаю такой вариант - "UIScrollView и всплывающая клавиатура - скролл к активному текстовому полю". Таким образом, заголовок вашего вопроса станет значительно более понятным при просмотре другими участниками ХК.

Comment: Спасибо! Идею понял, поиграюсь. Делегаты добавил :) 

У меня UITextField (ошибся в письме), но роли не играет :)

Comment: Ну да, там тоже самое. Просто вместо `UITextView *textView` -> `UITextField *textField`.

Comment: Заработало?

Comment: Заработало, но есть "глюк" не понятный :(
Как только я "выбираю" второе поле, у меня "съезжают" настройки scrollview, на не понятные мне. Откуда он их берет, не понимаю.

Comment: Форматирование лучше делать так: когда нужно показать код, редактируете вопрос, пишите внизу ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ №1 или №Х и пишите код, а в комментарии пишите см. обновление 1. Сделайте, пожалуйста. Особенно полезно такое цитирование своего кода в самом вопросе еще и тем, что на ХК стоит лимит на комментирование (штук 10 вроде лимит).

Comment: Поправил :) 

см. Обновление 1, там строка [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 400)]; второй раз не "выполняется"
мини-обновление: а, нет выполняется; но потом "кто-то" ее перехватывает и меняет данные.
ьини-обновление2: вынес установку в viewDidLoad и посмотрел. scrollview приходит с другими данными!??? Почему???

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, есть еще одна опция - UITableView. Каждое поле ввода находится в отдельной ячейке, а когда начинается ввод в то или иное поле (`textFieldShouldBeginEditing`, `textFieldDidBeginEditing `), то просто скроллим к нужной' ячейке (`scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:`)

' нужная ячейка не обязательно та, в которой находится фокус. К примеру, для первой ячейки не скроллить вообще, для второй скроллить к первой, для четвертой ко второй, и т.п., т.е. чтобы все поля ввода были видны в момент фокуса.